# Allignment Issue in Crystal report Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2008 and I am here having one main report and 3 other sub reports.I cannot able to make the position for the sub reports all are coming in different alignment. I just right click on the main report and insert sub report and browse the report. Its work fine.The problem are
 1) the allignment of the subreports
 2) how to hide a subreport when there is no value

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
You could try the following for 
 2) how to hide a subreport when there is no value

Right click on the "sub-report" and select "property"
On "Format Editor" -> "Common" Tab ->Click on the formula button beside "suppress" then you can try to write
COUNT({your datasource name ;1.fieldname})=0
that mean if the row count is 0 then suppress your subreport

if you add you subreport inside a section, you could do something similar to suppress the whole session.

Please correct me if my concept is wrong

Comment: Hi ShareChiWi I am using the collection class to set the Datasource of the subreport and the problem is that I cannot find the particular field name there. Let me try by adding